# Error when posting json using $http

Tags: angularjs, json

I have the following however I keep getting an error message about the period between the JSON and stringify.

```
var JsonObject = {};
JsonObject['key'] = '987';
JsonObject['val'] = '1234';
JsonObject['val2'] = '123';
JsonObject['val3'] = 1;
JsonObject['val4'] = 'test';
JsonObject['val5'] = 5;
console.log(JsonObject);

var req = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'api/call/run',
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, version=2'},
   data: {
      JSON.stringify(JsonObject)
   }
}
$http(req);
```

I need to return and pass this into a POST call for a rest service but it keeps saying that its not serialized so I'm trying to return the object as a json string.

I can return the object but again i get the serialize error.

How do i return the object as a json string?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
var req = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'api/call/run',
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, version=2'},
   data: JsonObject
}
$http(req);
```

Comment: Hello yes but I receive the following error: Invalid deserializer state...so i was trying to turn it into a json string

Comment: You mean the server returns "Invalid deserializer state" or the client when parsing the server response ?

Comment: In the chrome console that is the error the server returns, it doesn't like the format looks like....so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: What is the server expecting as data ?

Comment: Json, so I've passed the jsonobject but no luck. So now I'm trying to pass the stringified version...but I get an error.

Comment: Yes json, but what kind ? are you sure the server expects something with `{ key: string, val: string, val2: string, val3: int, val4: string, val5: int }` ?

Comment: Yep it wants something just like that...i saw another call that was done and that is exactly how it shows. Are there more than one json type?

Comment: Try to remove the `headers` line. Angular $http will default to json for an object post. Also, you should try to post with `curl` to test the server and see what json to send exactly.

Comment: I'll try that, do you know why the json.stringify doesn't work?

Comment: If you want to use the JSON.stringify, I think you need to remove the braces `{}` around the string, i.e. `data: JSON.stringify(JsonObject)`

Comment: Just use this way '$http.post('/api/call/run', JsonObject).then(successCallback, errorCallback)'  . You will be sending json object to the server and server will parse it back into json string.